# GWT - DoubleBox with more than 3 decimal places

Tags: gwt, double, truncate

I'm creating an user interface using GWT and there're many boxes of double values but when I set some variable which contains more than 3 decimal places my DoubleBox doesn't accept and truncates the number letting just 3 places.

Is it normal?

What's the best solution?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As the javadoc says `DoubleBox` is a `ValueBox` using a `DoubleParser` and `DoubleRenderer`. Those rely on `NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat()` which will trunk at 3 decimals in most (if not all) locales (for the default locale: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/i18n/client/constants/NumberConstantsImpl.properties)

If you want another format, then use a `ValueBox` with a `NumberFormatRenderer` with your custom `NumberFormat` pattern (and either use the `DoubleParser` or make your own `Parser` with your custom `NumberFormat` pattern)

Comment: What is the advantage of doing it this way than just going to a TextBox approach?

Comment: Encapsulation (of the behavior into the widget), integration with the Editor framework.