# Decimals in DoubleBox or TextBox in GWT

Tags: java, gwt, textbox, formatting, double

I am trying to create my own box where you can edit numbers only and they should be displayed with one decimal.

The declaration is simply
    `private static class NumTextBox extends DoubleBox //TextBox`
In the constructor I add
    `this.getElement().setAttribute("type", "number");`
This way I get up/down arrows and I also set the step and limits with
    `this.getElement().setAttribute("max", "12");
    this.getElement().setAttribute("min", "0");
    this.getElement().setAttribute("step", "0.5");`

When I set the value I get one decimal as intended. But when I step up/down the decimal is dropped in even values so I get 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3 and so on while I want 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0 and so on.

Using `setAttribute("decimals", "1");` and/or `setAttribute("format", "#0.0#");` does not appear to do anything.

I read that you could use `NumberFormatRenderer` to do this, but I haven't found anything on how that could be done.

Comment: Did you tried setAttribute("format", "0.#"); ?

Comment: Yes, same result (nothing). It's probably standard HTML behind and according to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12066436/styling-html5-input-type-number you can only set min, max and step.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245622/gwt-doublebox-with-more-than-3-decimal-places

Comment: Thanks Ümit, but that only works when you set the value, not when you are using the spinner.

Comment: One solution is to suppress the display of the spinner and then add my own spinner instead. That way I can have more control over it.