# GWT DoubleBox - change dot to comma

Tags: gwt

i would like to change point to comma when the user filled DoubleBox (same as excel).

any suggestion please thanks.

Comment: The solution here may be helpful: [GWT - DoubleBox with more than 3 decimal places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12245622/gwt-doublebox-with-more-than-3-decimal-places)

Comment: Excel also uses a period, not a comma, if you are in the U.S. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you do not set a locale for your app, all formatting is set using the default format. The easiest solution is to set the locale explicitly to the one that fits your needs, e.g.

```
<set-property name="locale" value="ru" />
```